# Adding Bootsrap 4 on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I recently read a lot of tutorials on online on how can I successfully install bootstrap 4 on the new version of Rails.

Here's the step I have taken so far:

1. `yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js`
2. in config/webpack/environment.js added the following:

   ```
   const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')        
   const webpack = require('webpack')
   environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
     Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
   }))

   module.exports = environment
   ```
3. in app/javascript/packs/application.js added the following:

   ```
   require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
   ```
4. in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css add the following:

   ```
   @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
   ```

I also tried adding a custom.scss file (_custom.scss file) on the same scss folder and tried to change the background color if it does.

Just to see if bootstrap is running I added a class table table-dark but did not work.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run this in a separate tab:

```
./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

If afterwards you get a "Compiled successfully" message from webpacker, then you're good to go! Otherwise it will show you the errors you need to fix in order for the assets to compile & load properly.

Comment: In complement, I recommend you to use the foreman gem, you will just have to type `foreman s` to launch your rails server and `webpack-dev-server` just with a procfile. for instance: ```web: bin/rails server
webpack: bin/webpack-dev-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq```

Comment: I'm just curious why I have to install foreman and create a procfile while I could run a one liner and fire at once :thinking:

Comment: This did not help me unfortunately: changing aplication.css to .scss the @import works as expected.